# I get an error when I try to create my own modifier for "textfield" in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to create my own modifier for "textfield" in swiftUI.
I created the following modifier in extension.

```
extension TextField{
    public func LoginInputStyle(_ flg:String = "1") -> TextField{
        
        if(flg == "1"){
            return self.font(.system(size: 16, design: .rounded))
                .frame(maxWidth: 300)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()) as! TextField<Label>
        }
        return self.font(.system(size: 16, design: .rounded))
            .frame(maxWidth: 300)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()) as! TextField<Label>
    }
}


struct NewLogin: View {
    @State public var mail:String = ""
    var body:some View{
       VStack(){
          TextField("input mailaddress",text: $mail).LoginInputStyle()
       }
    }
}
```

When I build the modifier, it stops with the following error

「Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftUI, SwiftUI._EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Swift.Optional<SwiftUI.Font>>, SwiftUI._FlexFrameLayout>, SwiftUI.TextFieldStyleModifier<SwiftUI.RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle>>' (0x7f9ea6833d48) to 'SwiftUI.TextField<SwiftUI.Text>' 」

How can I fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

to create your own modifier try this approach, using `ViewModifier`:

```
struct NewLogin: View {
    @State public var mail: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
       VStack() {
          TextField("input mailaddress",text: $mail)
               .modifier(TextFieldModifier(flg: "2"))
       }
    }
    
}

struct TextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    var flg: String = "1"
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if(flg == "1") {
            content
                .font(.system(size: 16, design: .rounded))
                .frame(maxWidth: 300)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        } else {
            content
                .font(.system(size: 16, design: .rounded))
                .frame(maxWidth: 300)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear answer!
I'm still trying to figure out how to write the above, but I've solved the error with no problem here!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to workingdog's answer, you can extend `View` to create the modifier - it saves you from writing "modifier" in your code.

The modifier:

```
extension View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func loginInputStyle(_ flg: String = "1") -> some View {
        
        if flg == "1" {
            self
                .font(.system(size: 16, design: .rounded))
                .frame(maxWidth: 300)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        } else {
            self
                .font(.system(size: 26, design: .rounded))
                .frame(maxWidth: 300)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

In the calling view:

```
    @State public var mail:String = ""

    var body:some View{
       VStack {
           TextField("input mailaddress", text: $mail)
                .loginInputStyle()
           TextField("input mailaddress", text: $mail)
                .loginInputStyle("2")
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear answer!
I learned that it can be done by using ViewBuilder and extending to the View!
And I was able to resolve the error here without any problem!
Thank you very much!